# How is parameter.method or argument.method possible? I thought it was always class.method. Can someone explain?

Tags: java

I am new to java and I always was taught it was always class.method and now this code which has another.getX is confusing me greatly. I never realized parameter or argument.method was possible Can someone explain how it works?

```
public class Point {
private int x;
private int y;

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public Point() {
    this(0,0);
}

public Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public double distance (){


    double distance = Math.sqrt((x - 0) * (x - 0) + (y - 0) * (y - 0));

   return distance;
}

public double distance (int x, int y){

    double distance = Math.sqrt((x-this.x) * (x-this.x) + (y-this.y) * (y - this.y));
    return distance;
}

public double distance (Point another){

    double distance =  Math.sqrt((another.x - x)   * (another.x - x) + (another.y - y)   * (another.y - y));
    return distance;
}
```

}

Comment: You can call a method on any object. You can always do `(expr).someMethod()` as long as `expr` is an object. Otherwise, what would be the point of making methods?

Comment: the code doesn't seem to have `another.getX` at all. It has `another.x` which won't work if `x` is private. Note that `another` is a variable that refers to an instance of `Point` so it really is a class. If  you had `another.getX()` that would be a class having its `getX` method called.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

As always for this kind of things, it is defined very well in the Java Language Specification, § 15.1. This is an excerpt:

> If an expression denotes a variable, and a value is required for use in further evaluation, then the value of that variable is used. In this context, if the expression denotes a variable or a value, we may speak simply of the value of the expression.

That means that `someObject.someMethod()` may produce a value with a result type.

Here's an example:

```
class A {
    B getB() {
        return new B();
    }
}
class B {
    C getC() {
        return new C();
    }
}
class C {
    String getString() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

You can "chain" your method calls like this:

```
A myA = new A();
String str = myA.getB().getC().getString().toUpperCase();
System.out.println(str); // Prints "HELLO WORLD!"
```

What happens is this:

- `myA` is an `A`.
- `A.getB()` returns a `B`.
- `B.getC()` returns a `C`.
- `C.getString()` returns a `String`.
- String.toUpperCase()`returns a`String`, thus the final result is a`String`, which is stored into the`str` variable.

---

A few more notes: `SomeClass.someMethod()` denotes a *static method*. The class name may be omitted if the current class is `SomeClass`. `someVariable.someMethod()`, however, is an *instance method*, it can only be called on an instance.